# "Будет дуть ветер" - можно ли так сказать?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Будет дуть ветер" - разве так можно?

Answer (score 1):

Фраза грамматически корректна, в чем сомнения?

Answer (score -1):

Можно, но так говорят только дети, а пишут - неграмотные люди. Покрасивее можно сказать: "завтра будет ветер" или "завтра будет ветрено".